Dynamic string passed in parameter of flutter localisation
I'm trying to pass dynamic string to flutter localisation method.
Here in this example i made a layout. The title placed on the appbar should be dynamic because the layout is used by many other pages.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:health_app_test/ui/containers/custom_drawer/custom_drawer.dart';

class PageScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget body;
  final String title;
  final String currentRoute; // Ajout de cette ligne

  const PageScaffold({
    super.key,
    required this.body,
    this.title = '', // Optional if you want to set it from outside
    required this.currentRoute, // Ajout de cette ligne
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var t = AppLocalizations.of(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: t![title]),
      drawer: CustomDrawer(
        currentRoute: currentRoute,
      ),
      body: body,
    );
  }
}


I get this error
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'AppLocalizations'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.dartundefined_operator


The problem is in that line     var t = AppLocalizations.of(context);
Are you sure that:  AppLocalizations.of(context); returns a Map<String,dynamic>
since it doesn't, the square brackets are not defined for t variable.
title: t![title] , t is not a Map to use square brackets to access its items.
Make sure AppLocalizations.of(context) is returning your expected result as Map<String,dynamic>.
